# Does a property with an empty setter take up memory space?

Tags: c#

Of the three properties below, does only `BarProp` require the 4 bytes memory per class instance?

```
class Foo
{
    int BarEmptySet { get { return 0; } set { } }
    int BarNoSet { get { return 0; } }
    int BarProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why would you suspect it to behave different than you suggest?

Comment: I'd say the early responses to the question justify its existence. One guy says the IL loads an int for all 3 properties in each instance; the next guy does not. I did not know the answer to the question, so I asked.

Comment: ILSpy or similar introspection tool is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler only generates a backing field for [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) (e.g. `BarProp`).  When you provide custom get/set implementations (e.g. `BarEmptySet` and `BarNoSet`) a backing field isn't automatically generated so they won't contribute to the object's memory footprint by themselves.

This can be easily verified by looking at the generated [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

**BarEmptySet:**

```
// getter
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0005
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     
IL_0006:  ret         

// setter
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret
```

**BarNoSet:**

```
// getter
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0005
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     
IL_0006:  ret   

// no setter is generated
```

**BarProp:**

```
// getter
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Foo.<BarProp>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

// setter
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Foo.<BarProp>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret
```

As you can see, only `BarProp` uses `stfld` to set a backing field and `ldfld` to return the backing field's value. Others just use the literal `0`.

Comment: I think they're only called AUTO properties when there's no explicit setter or getter. (So technically a backing field for auto properties is always created)

Comment: @realbart thanks for spotting that, I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as Im conserned, properties are in fact "sugar" which wraps fields of class in two methods: getter and setter by default.

But, it also can describe non-variable values, such as constants, functions and etc. So in your case it will instantiate only getter/setter function without background fields for all of your class instances, but the last one will perform its "default" duty - create hidden field which takes memory per class.

Comment: The answer should include evidence, e.g. a link to documentation or the compiled IL of the class.